# How can I reload my table from a different class?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to reload my table from another class. But it seems I can't.

```
myclass1.h
@interface CalendarViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {


UITableView *tablo;

myclass1.m

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }     


// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text=@"mytext";

    return cell;
}

and myclass2.m
`(NSDate*) dateSelected{

    CalendarViewController *cal1=[[CalendarViewController 

alloc]initWithNibName:@"CalendarViewController" bundle:nil];
[cal1.tablo  reloadData];


}
```

I don't know how I can solve this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you declared an iVar instead of using @property and @synthesize, you have to create the getters and setters yourself.

Instead of `UITableView *tablo;` in your header do this instead:

```
@interface CalendarViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong)UITableView *tablo;

@end
```

Then in the implementation file:

`@synthesize tablo = _tablo;`

Then you should be able to access cal1.tablo

Comment: it didnt accept strong. gave an error: unknown property attribute : strong.

Comment: Sorry. assumed your were using ARC. Use retain instead of strong. And make sure your release it in dealloc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a singleton or static method **(+)**.

```
+ (void) DoSomethingWithTable {
  // ...
}
```

and call it using `[ClassName DoSomethingWithTable]`